# PHP soap xml vs SoapUI xml

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I have a working SOAP UI xml, and I have my SOAP request XML and they are almost identical.  SOAP UI works, mine gets a null response. Here's the SOAPUI XML first

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:get="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/GetDetailsWebService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <get:AuthHeader>
         <get:CorpName>corp</get:CorpName>
         <get:UserId>1234</get:UserId>
         <get:Signature>ABC123</get:Signature>
      </get:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:GetDetails xmlns:get="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/GetDetailsWebService">
         <get:object_id>qwerty-123</get:object_id>
      </get:GetDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and here is my PHP code and the request.

```
$client=new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0));

$auth = array(
            'CorpName' => $CorpName,
            'UserId' => $username,
            'Signature' => $Signature
    );
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/GetDetailsWebService','AuthHeader',$auth,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$parm[] = new SoapVar($LOid, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'object_id' );


var_dump($client->GetDetails( new SoapVar($parm, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT) ));  //output is NULL
```

//and the PHP request:

print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/GetDetailsWebService">
           <SOAP-ENV:Header>
              <ns1:AuthHeader>
                 <ns1:CorpName>corp</ns1:CorpName>
                 <ns1:UserId>1234</ns1:UserId>
                 <ns1:Signature>ABC123</ns1:Signature>
              </ns1:AuthHeader>
           </SOAP-ENV:Header>
           <SOAP-ENV:Body>
              <ns1:GetDetails>
                 <object_id>qwerty-123</object_id>
              </ns1:GetDetails>
           </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I can't tell if I'm close to creating a good request, or miles off.  I'm working to make the PHP request match SOAPUI's since it works and mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contain the nearly same information. Namespace prefixes for element nodes are exchangeable and optional. So all these 3 variants are resolved to and element node with the local name `Envelope` in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`.

- `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`
- `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`
- `<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`

You can read the element name as `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}:Envelope`.

The same goes for the `get` vs `ns1` namespaces prefixes. They both resolve to the same actual namespace.

But the element `object_id` has no namespace in your XML. The sixth argument of the `SoapVar` constructor is the node namespace so you might want to try:

```
$namespace = 'http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/GetDetailsWebService';
$parm[] = new SoapVar($LOid, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'object_id', $namespace);
```